# Spring Security 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

when I run my app, I encounter a problem (404 not found). But without the classes SpringConfig and SecurityInitializer, my app works.

it's SecurityConfig

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder userBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Yehor").password("1111").roles("EMPLOYEE"));
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Maria").password("2222").roles("HR"));
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Yan").password("3333").roles("MANAGER", "HR"));
    }
}
```

It's SecurityInitializer

```
package basic;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

It's MyController

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getInfoForAllEmps(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("view_for_all");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @GetMapping("/hr-info")
    public String getInfoHr() {
        return "view_for_hr";
    }
    @GetMapping("/manager-info")
    public String getInfoManager() {
        return "view_for_manager";
    }
}
```

It's WebDisp

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebDisp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{Congif.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

It's Congif

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "basic")
public class Congif {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

It's pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spring.secutry</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled7</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>untitled7 Maven Webapp</name>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Web MVC -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>untitled7</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I did try change dependencies versions in pom.xml
Pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 5 and Tomcat 9 do not work with `jakarata` imports, but `javax` instead. Spring 6 works with Tomcat 10 but does not work with `javax`, but `jakarta` instead. Having any jakarta dependency/imports in your Spring 5/Tomcat 9 application will cause your application to fail.

So with that in mind:

```
Spring 5 + Tomcat 9 = javax imports

Spring 6 + Tomcat 10 = jakarta imports
```

I refactored your classes and pom.xml to meet those requirements:

Congif.java

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "basic")
public class Congif {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getInfoForAllEmps(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("view_for_all");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @GetMapping("/hr-info")
    public String getInfoHr() {
        return "view_for_hr";
    }
    @GetMapping("/manager-info")
    public String getInfoManager() {
        return "view_for_manager";
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserBuilder userBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Yehor").password("1111").roles("EMPLOYEE"));
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Maria").password("2222").roles("HR"));
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(userBuilder.username("Yan").password("3333").roles("MANAGER", "HR"));
    }
}
```

SecurityInitializer.java

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

WebDisp.java

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebDisp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{Congif.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>yes</groupId>
  <artifactId>yes</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  
    <!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-security-demo</finalName>
    
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>                    
                </plugin>                       
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
  
</project>
```

If withDefaultPasswordEncoder deprecated method bothers you, you can use the following code:

```
package basic;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("Yehor").password(passwordEncoder().encode("1111")).roles("EMPLOYEE")
            .and()
            .withUser("Maria").password(passwordEncoder().encode("2222")).roles("HR")
            .and()
            .withUser("Yan").password(passwordEncoder().encode("3333")).roles("MANAGER", "HR");
    }
}
```

In this refactored version, BCryptPasswordEncoder is used to encode passwords before storing them. The passwordEncoder() method is annotated with @Bean, which makes it available as a bean for dependency injection. Each password is encoded using this encoder before being stored.